# Selenium: How to click an HTML button element?

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, selenium-rc

I have button on the page that being used as a link to another page. So when the user clicks the button they are redirected to the right page.

I am using the Selenium extension for PHPUnit and I would like to test that the button is correctly redirecting the user. Here is the HTML that I am trying to test:

```
<button onclick="window.location='/sponsor';" value="Continue" type="button" id="sponsorContinue" name="sponsorContinue">Continue</button>
```

I have tried a lot of different approaches to click the button, but I can't seem to get any of them to work:

```
$this->click("//button[@id='sponsorContinue']");
```

This command executes and does not throw any errors, but the page isn't redirected. It works fine when I manually click the button. What should I do?

Comment: This snippet is working fine for me. What browser/OS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem...the HTML is wrong, and it's forcing users to use javascript to continue to the next page. Use this HTML instead. It's cleaner and doesn't rely on javascript.

```
<form method="get" action="/sponsor">
    <button type="submit" id="sponsorContinue">Continue</button>
</form>
```

Also, this will now work:

```
$this->click('sponsorContinue');
```

However, if you're trying to get `window.location` to work, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953946/selenium-how-to-click-buttons-that-use-onclick-window-location).

Comment: +1 for the Javascript-less solution. But still why isn't Selenium triggering the onclick event?

Comment: I agree with changing the button HTML in this case.  However if you need to fire events in the future Selenium lets you do this with fireEvent!

Comment: I have not tried Safari 4 but am sorry fireEvent isn't working.  While not "pure", you could click and use javaScript injection to manually call the onClick js function.