# Selenium RC: How to click buttons that use onclick window.location?

Tags: button, safari, selenium, phpunit, window.location

I have a button (outside of a form) that redirects to another page using the `onclick` attribute that calls `window.location` to redirect the user to another page. This time I can't change the HTML. I am using Safari 4 for testing. How can I click a button that uses the `onclick` attribute and `window.location` to redirect using Safari 4 and Selenium RC PHPUnit Extension?

Here's my HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location='/registrations/new'" value="Start a new registration" id="create">
```

**Update:** Alternatively, I'm thinking about doing something where I assert that a location is specified in the `window.location=''`, store that location, and call the `open()` command using that location. Not sure if this is an acceptable approach to testing this.

Comment: What happens when you click it, the standard way?

Comment: It works fine when you are clicking it manually. But it does not redirect when trying to click it with Selenium RC.

Comment: What happens when you run the test in another browser? I've tested this successfully in Firefox, is this just an issue with Safari?

Answer (score 2):

We decided to extend the default `clickAndWait()` functionality to call `openAndWait()` if the button has an `onclick="window.location='/something';"`

```
/**
 * Extends original clickAndWait() functionality to provide the ability to click buttons that use window.location to redirect users
 * @param $locator
 */
public function clickAndWait($locator)
{
    $this->assertElementPresent($locator);
    $hasOnclickAttribute = $this->getEval('this.browserbot.findElement("' . $locator . '").hasAttribute("onclick")');
    if ($hasOnclickAttribute === 'true') {
        $onclickValue = $this->getAttribute("$locator@onclick");
        if (strpos($onclickValue, "window.location=") !== false) {

            // Clean up the location
            $temp = explode("=" , $onclickValue);               
            $location = trim($temp[1], "';");               
            $location = trim($location, '"');

            return $this->openAndWait($location);
        }
    }
    return parent::clickAndWait($locator);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This *should* work, however you could also try firing the click event using the `fireEvent` command.

```
selenium.fireEvent("id=create", "click");
```